# Which is the best JavaScript Keyboard event library. (Hotkeys, Shortcuts )

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to make a BBS forum that using many Keyboard events,
so which is the best Keyboard event library?

Comment: "Best" is a hard criteria to match.  You might try giving some more detail on what you are trying to accomplish.  That way, we can be more specific.

Answer (score 34):

Just another to throw in the mix.  I recently released one called Mousetrap.  You can check out examples at http://craig.is/killing/mice

Comment: It is very easy to implement and works like a charm. How is the license for using it in commercial projects?

Comment: It uses the Apache 2.0 license.

Comment: It's a great library, but with one major weakness: It does not let you specify the container to bind the events to. It always binds to document. Which is why I had to add some extra focus checks into my callbacks. (My site contains two elements, each with different bindings.)

Comment: @Domi - As of 1.5 this is now fixed, I believe

Comment: Simple to use. Elegant functionality. Small. Plugins. Awesome!

Comment: Mousetrap has poor code quality and can't be required in a modern javascript build (https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap/issues/283) - highly suggest using keyboardjs

Comment: in 2019 this Library is broken for Firefox on Windows Systems.

Answer (score 13):

Try [KeyboardJS](http://robertwhurst.github.com/KeyboardJS/)

its as simple as

```
KeyboardJS.on('a', function(){ alert('hello!'); });
```

yet as flexible as

```
var bindInstance = KeyboardJS.on('ctrl + a, ctrl + b, c', function(event, keysPressedArray, keyComboString){

    //you get the event object
    console.log('event object', event);

    //you get the keys pressed array
    console.log('keys pressed', keysPressedArray);

    //you get the key combo string
    console.log('combo pressed', keyComboString);

    console.log('I will fire when \'ctrl + a\' or \'ctrl +b\' or \'c\' is pressed down');

    //block event bubble
    return false;

}, function(event, keysPressedArray, keyComboString) {

    console.log('I will fire on key up');

    //block event bubble
    return false;

});
```

you can clear a binding by calling

```
bindInstance.clear();
```

you can clear all binds with specific keys with

```
KeyboardJS.clear('a, b');
```

Its open source and available on [Github](http://github.com/RobertWHurst/KeyboardJS/). Its comes in ether a global library or an AMD module for RequireJS.

Here's an [introduction video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOtUXRrB350).

There, now stop worrying about the keyboard and code your app. ;)

Comment: Seems like a really great script, but as best I can tell it is not working in IE8, which is sadly a problem for me (on several levels).  When I go to http://robertwhurst.github.com/KeyboardJS/ with IE8 it just says "JS is required".

Comment: The demo may not work in IE but the library should. It did a couple builds ago. Did you try the library itself?

Comment: I did not.  I will give it a try.  Is there tweaking that the demo needs to show off that is can handle all of the browsers?  I would be happy to fork and tweak and send a pull request on the demo page.

Comment: That would be helpful. I'm really swamped with my current project and barley have time to sleep. If you fix the demo I'm accept your pull request.

Comment: This is the only library of the 4-5 I tested that actually worked for my situation (a `div` with `contenteditable="true"`). Thanks @RobertHurst!

Comment: Very nice library but I think the API has changed from "KeyboardJS.bind.key" to "KeyboardJS.on".

Comment: We are using the KeyboardJS lib and it is nice library but it made a HELL to us when we are using dev tools, and it is constantly taking over and REFIRING the old triggered key event, even we do not press it anymore?! :)  but some other key, etc, etc => be careful.  

P.S. that was a bit older version, but still in my opinion really annoying for our clients

Comment: Also, @RobertHurst it is a good policy that you note in your post that you are author of the library that you are suggesting :)

Comment: @mPrinC KeyboardJS cannot re-fire DOM events. It does not contain any logic to do so. It simply listens for events. Anything before that is controlled by your browser or other JS code.

Comment: @mPrinC I haven't obfuscated that it's my library, and I'm not sure why that's important. It's my personal solution, and this is my personal answer. I'm certainly not forcing it on anyone, and in fact, I didn't have to share it to begin with. That said, if you are having trouble with it, you're welcome to contact me. I will help you.

Answer (score 3):

[KEYPRESS](http://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/) is focused on game input and supports any key as a modifier, among other features. It's also [pre-packaged for Meteor](https://atmospherejs.com/keypress/keypress).

Answer (score 2):

From what I have seen Mousetrap is the only library that let's you specify key *sequences* rather than combinations. This came in very handy for my application.

Comment: Actually, KeyboardJS has that feature, too.

Answer (score 1):

This one is pretty good for jquery.

https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Answer (score 1):

Lots of JavaScript libraries come replete with ways of capturing key input and using it to your advantage.  It's a good bet that you will be able to find a library to do just that, and nothing else.  I don't have a lot of experience there, however.

I've been using [Ext](http://www.extjs.com) for a while now, and their [KeyMap](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.KeyMap) class is really easy to work with.  Here is a simple example using it.

```
new Ext.KeyMap(Ext.getDoc(), {
        key: 'abc',
        alt: true,
        handler: function(k, e) {
            var t = Ext.getCmp('tabpanel');
            switch(k) {
                case 65:
                    t.setActiveTab(0);
                    break;
                case 66:
                    t.setActiveTab(1);
                    break;
                case 67:
                    t.setActiveTab(2);
                    break;
            }
        },
        stopEvent: true
    });
```

This takes class, [Ext.TabPanel](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.TabPanel), and allows the user to push a keyboard key to change tabs, rather than clicking the tabs themselves.

It can, of course, do much more than this.  This is a simple example of how it works though.

Answer (score -1):

This one is better if you are starting and if you want to understand how hot-keys work.

https://github.com/UthaiahBollera/HotkeysInJavascriptLibrary

Answer (score -3):

You can try this one...

http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: -1: This isn't a library - just a reference